# How to to use `v-for` with Bootstrap-Vue's `b-col` and `b-row`?

Tags: vue.js, layout, bootstrap-vue

How can we incorporate Bootstrap-Vue layouts into a v-for that outputs into an imported Vue component?

This is the setup I've tried...

```
<b-container>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="6">
      ...
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="6" v-for="item in items">
      <ComponentName></ComponentName>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

The intent is to get a result that looks something along these lines:

### What I DO want

[image: Intended Outcome]

But the result is different. It does the "50/50" column split for the FIRST `v-for` `Component`, but the remaining `Component`'s are "broken out" and no longer placed beside the left `b-column` area. It looks something like this:

### What I do NOT want, how it currently looks

[image: Actual Outcome]

How can I inform the layout to keep the two columns side by side through all of the `v-for` items, rather than just the first?

Thank you in advance for any insights or tips! In the meantime, I'll keep reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a nested container and loop through its rows using v-for :

```
<b-container>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="6">
      ...
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="6" >
    <b-container >
     <b-row v-for="item in items"> 
      <b-col sm="12" >
         <ComponentName></ComponentName>
       </b-col>
     </b-row>
    </b-container>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

---

Edit by @Spectator6:

Thanks to @Boussadjra's comment, I discovered I was mis-placing the `v-for` directive. Rather than use it on the "parent" column, it should contain a new "child" row, with the `v-for` directive applied there. So the end result looks something like this:

```
<b-container>
  <b-row>
    <b-col sm="6">
      ...
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="6">
      <b-row v-for="item in items">
        <ComponentName></ComponentName>
      </b-row>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

Thanks again for your help @Boussadjra!

Comment: Hello @Boussadjra! Thanks, your suggestion helped! Turns out it didn't need a nested container, I just needed to apply the v-for to the row within the right column. I was previously applying the v-for to the "parent" column.

Comment: @Spectator6 I don't think there's any reason to use `<b-row>` (that you placed the `v-for` on) unless the root of `<ComponentName>` is `<b-col>`. You could just replace it with a normal `<div>`. You could also just put `v-for` on the `<ComponentName>` element itself depending on how it's structured..